# Are Visual Studio 2012 product keys backwards compatible

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone have any experience with using product keys for VS2012 within VS2010?

I need to run VS2010 for my current project (some design-time components are not yet compatible with VS2012), and so need to purchase a product key.

However, MS have stopped selling keys for 2010! The VS2012 whitepaper states:

> For Visual Studio Professional, the software included in the license is the current version >of the software, Visual Studio Professional 2012, plus the right to simultaneously run prior >versions of Visual Studio Professional to which you may otherwise have access.

This really doesn't make it clear whether the product key will be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retail edition of Visual Studio 2012 Professional does not allow you to license previous versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and run VS 2010 professional with a 2012 license.

Comment: Just bought a VS2012 license key, and this doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't get the MSDN version?

Comment: Sadly, no. MSDN pricing was outside of our budget. Thanks for your help though.